# Adapter returning null when calling method fragment in ParentActivity?

Tags: java, android

In my Activity i want to access a public method from my fragment which refreshes the data.

**I call this in the parentActivity which hosts my fragments:**

```
@Override
    public void onRescanLibrary() {
        Fragment songsFrag = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
        ((SongsFragment)songsFrag).refreshAdapter();
        Log.d(TAG,"onRescanLibrary called!");
}
```

But i don't now why my Adapter (**allSongsAdapter**) is returning null because onCreateView is called where i initialize the adapter.

**OnCreateView and Method in my fragment which i want to call in the parentActivity**

```
private AllSongsAdapter allSongsAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

allSongsAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter();

}

public void refreshAdapter(){
        if (Main.songs.getSongs() != null) {
            if (allSongsAdapter != null) {
                allSongsAdapter.updateList(Main.songs.getSongs());
                Log.d(TAG, "refreshAdapter called!");
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG,"allSongsAdapter is null!");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance that "onRescanLibrary" is called before "onCreateView" of that fragment?

Comment: If you've implemented your `PagerAdapter` like you should, `getItem()` is returning a brand new instance of that `Fragment`; one that's not been attached to the `FragmentManager`, and therefore has not gone through any lifecycle methods. You should be returning a new instance there, so that's not the problem. It's that you can't use `getItem()` to get a currently-active `Fragment` instance. You'll need to keep track of the instances your giving to the `ViewPager` – e.g., in a `Map<Integer, Fragment>` – and get your current instance from that.

Comment: @MikeM What about using mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem, seems to work to get the active instance.

Comment: That might cause some issues, because that method performs the necessary `FragmentTransaction`, depending on the current `Fragment` state, and which particular `Fragment*PagerAdapter` you're subclassing. I've not done any testing, but I would imagine that it could at least mess with the `ViewPager`'s off-screen page tracking. It's probably safer to just keep track of your `Fragment` instances yourself. That's what I'd do, anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. I'm also using offscreenpagelimit set to the number of fragments, so i think i'm quite safe using this method right?

Comment: Possibly. That's just the first issue that came to mind. There could be other things I'm not thinking of, atm.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok thanks for the advice, better safe than sorry and just store them myself.